# Why does setInterval return the same value when using the Date method

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to get the local seconds from the `getSeconds` but when I `console.log` the results by adding the function in `setInterval` the seconds are the same yet they are increasing. please find my code below;

```
const time = new Date();
function clock() {
   const seconds = time.getSeconds();
   console.log(seconds)
}
let interval = setInterval('clock()', 1000);
```

Comment: Because you don't create a new value. new Date is calling once only.

Comment: New data is created every time you call `new Date();`. How many times does your code call `new Date();`?

Comment: Move the `new Date()` inside the function

Comment: am new to coding, but thank you for your help.

Comment: If an answer helped you don't forget to accept it.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the value for *time* outside (and only once) of your interval-func, therefore it's always the same. Try:

```js
function clock() {
  let time = new Date();
  const seconds = time.getSeconds();
  console.log(seconds)
}
let interval = setInterval('clock()', 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you create one data object (in some moment) and then you call getSeconds on the same data object so you have the same result

```js
function clock() {
  const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
  console.log(seconds)
}

let interval = setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the first line in your code because its useless now since you call `new Date()` inside the `clock` function.

Comment: @Yousaf Wow you are quick, I was just about to mention that.. ;)